# Determine if uploaded PDF is editable using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Can we determine if PDF is editable or not using PHP?

I have a PDF form. If user uploads such a PDF then I have to force User to click on SUBMIT button of PDF.

To implement this functionality I have to determine if PDF is editable or not.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestions that you might have

Comment: Editable in the sense of file permissions? Or editable in the sense that whatever PDF library you are using will not choke on it? Or editable in the sense that no PDF enforced restrictions apply?

Comment: I want to validate that user have uploaded PDF which contains a FORM that is PDF should have FORM (field name and input fields) which user can submit to some particular web page.

Comment: @yogesh I know this is the very old question, but I am looking for the same solution and below <</AcroForm solution is not working for me. If you still remember the solution can you please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to search for the text string `<</AcroForm` in the file:

```
<?php

$s = file_get_contents("test.pdf");
$has_form = preg_match('/<<\s*AcroForm\b/', $s);

?>
```